# Google map takes a lot of time to load with current location in Flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-flutter

I am trying to open google map with current location. For this, I am using a stateful widget. But map takes a lot of time to load, sometimes cant even load at all. Is this becuase of a `Future` function(for getting current location) or my implementation is wrong? I am using [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) plugin for map. Here is my code :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          FutureBuilder(
            future: _getCurrentLocation(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                print("map loaded");
                Placemark placemark = snapshot.data;
                var json = placemark.toJson();
                selectedLocation = TheLocation.fromJson(json);
                _markers.add(
                  Marker(
                    markerId: MarkerId('homeMarker'),
                    position: LatLng(
                        selectedLocation.latitude, selectedLocation.longitude),
                    icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
                    infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: selectedLocation.name),
                    draggable: false,
                  ),
                );
                return GoogleMap(
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: LatLng(placemark.position.latitude,
                        placemark.position.longitude),
                    zoom: 18,
                  ),
                  markers: _markers,
                  onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
                  onCameraMove: ((_position) => _updatePosition(_position)),
                );
              } else {
                print("loading map");
                return Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text("Loading map. Please Wait ... ..."),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Using [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator) plugin for getting current location :

```
Future<Placemark> _getCurrentLocation() async {
    List<Placemark> placeMarks;
    await geolocator
        .getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((Position position) async {
      placeMarks = await Geolocator().placemarkFromCoordinates(
        position.latitude,
        position.longitude,
        localeIdentifier: "en_US",
      );
    }).catchError((e) {
      print("Location error $e");
    });
    return placeMarks[0];
  }
```

`onMapCreated` function :

```
void onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    setState(() {
      googleMapController = controller;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Check internet connection, It's working correctly.

Comment: Yeah, It's working, but slow a bit.

Comment: then may be problem with TheLocation.fromJson because i run your code without that and marker code.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like this is a known issue. Check this [Git Issue link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28493). As suggested in the last comment, as a workaround you can create a `FutureBuilder` with a simulated delay as the future and then use a progress indicator to show the loading.